# post picture to blogger By Microsoft Office Word

Tags: ms-word, blogger

How i can use MS Word 2013 to post picture to Bloogger

Ask me About Picture Provider

and i don't know what is Provider my blog use for upload image

thanks

Comment: Have you configured at least posting to Blogger without pictures? By me it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you are blogging using www.blogger.com, i.e blogspot, then your hosting for images will be through online picasa web album. you will need upload pictures on picasa and then put the HTML code of your image on blogger, compost mode and add image option.